# Embedded web browser engine for cross platform desktop application?

Tags: cross-platform, browser, desktop-application

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to embed a web browser control in a cross-platform application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721201/how-to-embed-a-web-browser-control-in-a-cross-platform-application)

I'd like to embed a browsing engine (HTML,JS,CSS,DOM) in my desktop applications.
Which one is most suitable for me if I want to use it in a cross-platform desktop application?

Should I stick to one specific or write my own abstraction layer on top of the natives ones?

Update: A solution needs to provide an option for at least Windows/Mac/Linux.

Comment: Removed embedded tag used for embedded/real time related questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I ...
>   write my own abstraction layer on top
>   of the natives ones?

Having struggled with this exact issue, I think this is the only safe option at the moment. Something like Webkit on *nix, and Internet Explorer on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

WebKit is very lightweight and runs on all platforms. You will have to look at Google Chrome to see how to embed it into a Windows application. I believe it's native to GTK. There are also bindings for wxWidgets / wxPython.

Answer (score 2):

Qt is highly optimised, cross-platform yet native-looking, usable from C++, Java and Python, and includes WebKit.

Comment: Used QT for different purposes, but can confirm quality and good support, they are nokia now hope it's still good as it was.

Answer (score 2):

[Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com) might serve your needs-- it's a cross platform (Windows and Mac OSX) library based off of Google Chromium intended to help users embed a full-featured browser in their applications. It's free for non-commercial use and has a C++ API.